# Failed to import ArrayResult. No Apache Arrow result set format can be used. ImportError: No module named 'snowflake.connector.snow_logging'

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pyinstaller

I generated one `.exe` file from my python script using `pyinstaller --onefile file.py` with Pycharm. By executing the generated `.exe` file I get the error:

> Failed to import ArrayResult. No Apache Arrow result set format can be used.
> ImportError: No module named 'snowflake.connector.snow_logging'.

How can I fix this?

generate one `.exe` file from python script which imports data from snowflake database to pandas dataframe and export the result to onedrive folder.

Answer (score 1):

solved. I added `hiddenimports=['snowflake.connector.snow_logging']` to the `.spic` file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).